# How to add title to breadcrumb from the database of extention in typo3?

Tags: typo3, breadcrumbs, typoscript

Using kickstart i created one extension for listing category and product.And i need to display the both category title/name & product title/name in my breadcrumb .At present i coded for calling from the database(" 40 = RECORDS") it is only showing the

RESULT :- HOME > Page Name »

My Url:-http://www.domain.com/page_name/

```
       lib.breadcrumb=COA
       lib.breadcrumb {
        40 = RECORDS
        40 {
             dontCheckPid = 1
             tables = TABLE_NAME
             source.data = GPvar:tx_pi1_NAME|EXTKEY
             conf.EXTKEY = TEXT
             conf.EXTKEY.field = FIELD_NAME
             wrap = &nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp; |
           }


          10 = HMENU
          10 {
              special = rootline
       # "not in menu pages" should show up in the breadcrumbs menu
      includeNotInMenu = 1
           1 = TMENU
             # no unneccessary scripting.
           1.noBlur = 1
             # Current item should be unlinked
           1.CUR = 1
           1.target = _self
           1.wrap = <div class="breadcrumb-class"> | </div>
           1.NO {
             stdWrap.field = title
             ATagTitle.field = nav_title // title
             linkWrap = ||*| > |*|
            }
             # Current menu item is unlinked
           1.CUR {
             stdWrap.field = title
             linkWrap = ||*| &nbsp>&nbsp&nbsp |*|
             doNotLinkIt = 1
           }

          }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from the news extension. You can use the same approach for your extension.

http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-news/wiki/Add_news_to_breadcrumb_menu

Comment: Yes thank you , I gone with that code it is not working properly. it not showing in any warring or error .It is active in one single case.

Answer (score 0):

We can add field title to breadcrumb from the database of any extention that which we create in typo3.

```
lib.breadcrumb = COA
lib.breadcrumb {
    stdWrap.wrap = <ul class="breadcrumb">|</ul>
    entryLevel = 1

    10 = HMENU
    10 {
         special = rootline

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1

            NO = 1
            NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
                ATagTitle.field = subtitle // title
                linkWrap = ||*|&nbsp;&rsaquo;&nbsp |*|
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }

            CUR <.NO
            CUR {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
            }
        }
    }

    101=RECORD
    101 {
        tables = tx_table_name
        source.data =  GPvar:tx_plugin_name|param  //param passing in the url
        conf.tx_besiproduct_product = TEXT
        conf.tx_besiproduct_product.field = field_name
        conf.tx_besiproduct_product.required = 1
        conf.tx_besiproduct_product.wrap =  <li >|</li>
     }
}
```